# ACF Taxonomy Name

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i really hope someone can help a novice here.

So in ACF i have created a repeater with the name client_logos.

I have then created a sub_field image and a sub_field client_sector, which is a Taxonomy with return value Term ID.

So the output of the images is as expected and instead of the Taxonomy name i get the Taxonomy ID, which i guess is self explanatory seeing as i have a return value Term ID.

My query is how to get the actual taxonomy name ? My code is below.

```
<?php if( have_rows('client_logos') ): 
                        $counter = 1;
                        while ( have_rows('client_logos') ) : the_row(); 
                            $image = get_sub_field('image');
                            $sector = get_sub_field('client_sector')?>

                            <?php if($counter % 5 === 1 ): ?>
                                <div class="homepage-clients-logos-block__block-of-six">
                                    <div class="homepage-clients-logos-block__block-of-six-inside">
                            <?php endif; ?>

                                <div class="homepage-clients-logos-block__single">
                                    <img src="<?= $image['sizes']['large'] ?>">
                                    <h4 style="color:#fff;"><?= $sector ?></h4>
                                </div>

                            <?php if($counter % 5 === 0 || $counter === count($client_logos)): ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif;

                            $counter++; 
                        endwhile; 
                    endif; ?>
```

I have tried changing the Return Value to Term Object, but that causes a fatal error.

I would greatly appreciate any direction on this .

Comment: “but that causes a fatal error” - what is the error?